# Change entertainment area via Hue Sync Box API

Tags: philips-hue

I am leveraging the [Hue Sync Box API](https://developers.meethue.com/develop/hue-entertainment/hue-hdmi-sync-box-api) and I am able to control the settings like sync mode, and intensity. However, I am unable to change `hueTarget` to change the entertainment area in use.

This is my request:
`PUT https://hue_sync_box_ip/api/v1/execution`

Headers:

```
'Content-Type': 'application/json; charset=utf-8'
'Authorization': 'Bearer <token>'
```

Body:

```json
{"hueTarget": "/groups/c5cecc67-52e8-4f48-9d8d-433634daa9a1"}
```

The response I get is a `400 error` with this body

```json
{"code":15,"message":"Invalid Value"}
```

As per documentation, this is the problem:

> The key exists and the value type matches, but it is not according to the specified format or range.

The documentation on hueTarget is this:

- hueTarget
- Get, Put
- string, enum
- Currently selected entertainment area (/groups/ for entertainment group on bridge api v1, and entertainment configuration  in UUID format for bridge api v2)

The method is put, the key is valid as per error message, the value type matches string, and I am following the `/groups/<id>` that is required on v1.

These are my groups. The id I've used matches the "Streaming" which is the group (entertainment area) to which I was trying to change.

```json
   ...
    "hue": {
        "bridgeUniqueId": "001788FFFE6A3B07",
        "bridgeIpAddress": "<redacted>",
        "groupId": "ef023ba4-71bc-4b8b-a7ad-f86dd68356a4",
        "groups": {
            "ef023ba4-71bc-4b8b-a7ad-f86dd68356a4": {
                "name": "Living Room TV",
                "numLights": 5,
                "active": false
                "active": true
            },
            "c5cecc67-52e8-4f48-9d8d-433634daa9a1": {
                "name": "Streaming",
                "numLights": 3,
                "active": false
            }
        },
        "connectionState": "connected"
    },
  ...
```

I have also tried leveraging the hue endpoint with the same results:

This is my request:
`PUT https://hue_sync_box_ip/api/v1/hue`

Headers:

```
'Content-Type': 'application/json; charset=utf-8'
'Authorization': 'Bearer <token>'
```

Body:

```json
{
    "groups":
      {
          "c5cecc67-52e8-4f48-9d8d-433634daa9a1": {
              "active": true
          }
      }
}
```

The response I get is a `400 error` with this body

```json
{"code":15,"message":"Invalid Value"}
```

This matches the documentation: `groups/<id>/ active    Get, Put    boolean`.

I am also able to set the entertainment area manually on the app.

Any thoughts on what could be the issue here? I do think this code used to work at some point, but I am not sure as to confirm it for certain.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've managed to make it work. Instead of sending `/groups/<id>` as per documentation, you should only send `<id>`.

In other words, the body of the first call should be:

```json
{"hueTarget": "c5cecc67-52e8-4f48-9d8d-433634daa9a1"}
```

instead of the original

```json
{"hueTarget": "/groups/c5cecc67-52e8-4f48-9d8d-433634daa9a1"}
```